# rotate gesture in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, image-rotation

I want to capture the rotate gesture of an object in my Windows Phone app and animate the object to show that it has roatated.

I saw that WP7 doesn't give this gesture by default and i dint get the same in Toolkit as well. Can anyone help me get started.

Comment: Please clarify why a negative vote is for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the Multitouch behavior for the Windows Phone. 
The tool kit is available here:

http://multitouch.codeplex.com/

And these links might help you understand it better:

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/gestures-in-wp7-the-basic

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Windows-Phone-7-Silverlight-Programming-MultiTouch-and-Manipulation.aspx

Comment: Thanks Prashant, let me have a look at this.